# Order a container by member with STL

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, containers

Suppose I have some data stored in a container of `unique_ptr`s:

```
struct MyData {
    int id;  // a unique id for this particular instance
    data some_data; // arbitrary additional data
};

// ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyData>> my_data_vec;
```

The ordering of `my_data_vec` is important.  Suppose now I have another vector of IDs of MyDatas:

```
std::vector<int> my_data_ids;
```

I now want to rearrange `my_data_vec` such that the elements are in the sequence specified by `my_data_ids`.  (Don't forget moving a `unique_ptr` requires move-semantics with `std::move()`.)

What's the most algorithmically efficient way to achieve this, and do any of the STL algorithms lend themselves well to achieving this?  I can't see that `std::sort` would be any help.

Edit: I can use O(n) memory space (not too worried about memory), but the IDs are arbitrary (in my specific case they are actually randomly generated).

Comment: Are the `id`s arbitrary, or do they happen to be 0...n-1?

Comment: Edited the question to answer those points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a map that maps ids to their index in `my_data_ids`.
2. Create a function object that compares `std::unique_ptr<MyData>` based on their ID's index in that map.
3. Use `std::sort` to sort the `my_data_vec` using that function object.

Here's a sketch of this:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
typedef std::vector<int> my_data_ids_type;
typedef std::map<int,my_data_ids_type::size_type> my_data_ids_map_type;

class my_id_comparator : public std::binary_function< bool
                                                    , std::unique_ptr<MyData>
                                                    , std::unique_ptr<MyData> > {
public:
  my_id_comparator(const my_data_ids_map_type& my_data_ids_map)
    : my_data_ids_map_(my_data_ids_map) {}

  bool operator()( const std::unique_ptr<MyData>& lhs
                 , const std::unique_ptr<MyData>& rhs ) const
  {
     my_data_ids_map_type::const_iterator it_lhs = my_data_ids_map_.find(lhs.id);
     my_data_ids_map_type::const_iterator it_rhs = my_data_ids_map_.find(rhs.id);
     if( it_lhs == my_data_ids_map_.end() || it_rhs == my_data_ids_map_.end() )
       throw "dammit!"; // whatever
     return it_lhs->second < it_rhs->second;
  }
private
  my_data_ids_map_type& my_data_ids_map_;
};

//...

my_data_ids_map_type my_data_ids_map;
// ...
// populate my_data_ids_map with the IDs and their indexes from my_data_ids
// ...
std::sort( my_data_vec.begin(), my_data_vec.end(), my_id_comparator(my_data_ids_map) );
```

If memory is scarce, but time doesn't matter, you could do away with the map and search the IDs in the `my_data_ids` vector for each comparison. However, you would have to be *really* desperate for memory to do that, since two linearly complex operations per comparison are going to be quite expensive.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, thanks!  Didn't think `sort` would be applicable but you proved me wrong :) (btw I'm using C++0x so I used a lambda in the sort - keeps things a bit tidier)

Comment: @James: I'm not sure throwing a `std::exception` is right at this place. The way the problem was presented, it seems like there __must__ be an entry in `my_data_ids` for each ID. If so, then that should probably be an assertion instead, since failure would indicate that a pre-condition doesn't hold. Since I know too little about the problem, I did something obviously wrong and accompanied it by that comment, hoping it would be obvious that this needs more consideration. But maybe you're right. _"Do as I say, not as I do"_ usually doesn't very work well. What do you suggest?

Comment: @sbi:  I just meant that as a joke :-)  (Then I decided it wasn't funny so I deleted it)  As for my opinion, in this scenario, I tend to throw a `logic_error` or something derived therefrom.

Comment: @James: No offense taken, but I am always wary of posting code that's actually wrong or does things one should not do. As I said _"Do as I say, not as I do"_ doesn't work, I know that from teaching.

Comment: I think that the time complexity of this solution could be higher than you might like. Each comparision is O(log n) rather than O(1), so the total time is O(n*(log n)^2) instead of the usual O(n*log(n)). This might not matter, but if it does then using a std::unordered_map rather than a std::map would be better.

Comment: @Richard: That's a good point. I'd be very interested in a better solution should someone find one.

Comment: How about 1) Create a map of id to pointer; 2) clear the original list; 3) for each id in id list, push back the pointer by looking up its id in the map.  Isn't that O(n*log(n))?

Comment: @sbi: My suggestion was to use std::unordered_map which gives constant time access to elements in the best case. Just make sure that the hash function in use is appropriate.

Comment: @Richard: I understood that you suggested using a hash map. `:)` I was thinking of reducing memory usage and the first n in O(n*log n^2). Can't we get away without creating that map? For example, assuming we could change `my_data_ids` into a heap, we would at least reduce the memory footprint. And better data locality in a `std::vector` (compared with a `std::map`) practically might improve the algorithm despite all the theoretical O-ness. I was fishing for improvements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try moving the data into a STL Set ? you need only to implement the comparison function, and you will end up with a perfectly ordered set of data very fast.

Comment: Good idea - but the ordering of my_data_vec is significant and arbitrary.  The ordering information is lost by a set.

Comment: "Why don't you try moving the data into a STL Set?" Because then they wouldn't be in th order specified by `my_data_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a `map<int, unique_ptr<MyData>>` (or `multimap`)?